# Select and upload array of images

Tags: react-native

How to display one by one image and upload to database in react native

Every image should be append to the array and display

Answer (score 0):

Push every image data to array

```
this.state.imageholder.push(response.data);
```

Display and remove

```
  viewImages() {

return this.state.imageholder.map((image, key) => {
  return (

    <View style={{ flex: 2, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>

      <View style={styles.ImageContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.ImageContainer} source={image} />
        <Text onPress={() => this.removeImage(image)} style={styles.removeContainer} >Remove</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.space} ></Text>

      </View>
    </View>


  )
})
```

}

```
  removeImage(key) {
this.setState({
  imageholder: this.state.imageholder.filter(function (img) {
    return img !== key
  })
});
```

}

In render

```
              <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>

            {this.viewImages()}

          </ScrollView>
```